# Android camera stream with rtmp has stable 5 second latency

Tags: android, video, ffmpeg, h.264, rtmp

I use ffmpeg with h264 build and javacv on android to stream video from camera to rtmp server.
I was trying to set all possible video framerates and bitrates, set preset ultrafast, but I still have stable 5 seconds delay.
If i use android mediarecorder sending mpegts stream with rtmp to server,i have only 2 seconds delay, and if I use -fflags nobuffer  options on the client(ffmpeg), the video is appearing immediately.

I don`t know how in android ffmpeg reduces this latency.
Here the code:

```
    recorder = new FFmpegFrameRecorder(ffmpeg_link, imageWidth, imageHeight, 1);
    recorder.setFormat("flv");
    recorder.setFrameRate(frameRate);
    recorder.setVideoBitrate(900*1000);
    recorder.setVideoCodec(avcodec.AV_CODEC_ID_H264);
    recorder.setVideoOption("preset", "ultrafast");
    recorder.setVideoOption("tune", "zerolatency");
    recorder.setVideoOption("fflags", "nobuffer");
    recorder.setVideoOption("analyzeduration", "0");
```